# Windows refuses to shrink volume beyond a certain limit, but I need to clone the data, what do I do?

Tags: windows, disk-space, disk-cloning

My old hard drive, that I am currently using, is about 600GB and my new SSD is 500gb.

My actual data is only about 70GB to be cloned. However I learned that I have to shrink the volume to be able to clone.

The problem is Windows tells me I am only able to shrink 115GB because it won’t go past “unmovable files.”

I don’t understand it and ive never encountered something like that before. 115GB is not enough, I need to shrink it further, because of course, I’m not getting my entire 500GB on my SSD.

Comment: I got many results when searching for ["unmovable files"](https://superuser.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22unmovable%20files%22). Have you seen them? Have you tried anything? What version of Windows are we talking about?

Comment: For me most of the times it was necessary to disable swapping and remove recovery points (Win 10) to be able to shrink further. But there are plenty of guides out there which describe the process. But make a backup of your data first, then also maybe use clonezilla to be able to start from scratch with a working system. Clonezilla has saved me a couple of times!

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski omg, thank you, i just didn’t imagine there was something i can do about it, ill let you know what it comes to..

Comment: No need to do that, I use Macrium reflect Free version 8 to cone larger hard drives to smaller ones all the time. Scroll down to Reflect 8 Free on this page>>>https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski All is good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows has the bad habit of placing essential Windows files at the end
and the middle of the system disk.
These files are unmovable, probably because Windows addresses
them directly by sector-number, so become a problem when resizing
down the disk.

you should first
disable the page-file and swap space, then defragment the disk to move all
sectors to its begining, and resize only using Disk Management.
Return the above after the resize.

To reduce the Windows partition to the minimum:

- Turn off hibernation
- Disable the page-file
- Empty the Recycle Bin
- Defragment the disk with a third-party product the allows choosing a defragmentation mode that consolidates empty space at the end of the disk
- Resize the disk to a size that still leaves several giga of free space
- Clone the disk
- In the cloned system, undo the above manipulations.

Comment: I read I should disable system recovery too.. Thnx for the comprehensive reply

Comment: it's not a bad habit of Windows because ext4 even scatter both filesystem metadata and file contents across the whole partition because it allows the best average seek time on HDDs. Windows on FAT32 preferred to put everything at the beginning of the drive for fast sequential read/write speed but that doesn't work well so NTFS changed to the Linux way